# button inside href

Tags: php, html, button, href

Is it ok to write like this?

```
<a href="add-lead-new.php" target="rightframe"><input type="button" value="New booking" /></a>
```

The link should look like a button but it should open in the right part of the page. If its wrong, is there any other way to do it?
The above code works fine. i just don't know if its the correct way to do it.
Thanks

Comment: _technically_ you can add any _inline_ element except `<a>` in an `<a>` AFAIK, but I wouldn't do this as I'm not sure how different user agents will react, or even if they react the same at all. I'd just style some `<span>` to look like a button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not allowed according to the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).

- [The `<button>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) is considered "interactive content".
- [The `<a>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) must contain "no interactive content".

The button will probably show up, but since you're violating the specification it may not behave as you want. You should avoid doing this.

---

The most reliable to way to make a button bring the user to a page is to create a `<form>` that `target`s that page, and make the button submit that form.

```
<form action="add-lead-new.php"><input type="submit" value="New Booking" /></form>
```

Comment: the problem is i want the page to open in the right frame. in href i can write it as target="rightframe" but i don't know how to do that in button.

Comment: @Phphelp Try `<form action="add-lead-new.php" target="rightframe">`.

Answer (score 3):

no, the button itself wont do anything - it's only usefull with javascript to trigger any functions. 
you should use css to make some of your links like a button: http://www.zurb.com/article/266/super-awesome-buttons-with-css3-and-rgba

Comment: +1 -- I agree, using css is a cleaner way to separate the concerns.

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="button" value="New booking" onclick="self.frames['rightframe'].location.href='add-lead-new.php'"/>`

would be ok

Comment: You might want to put an absolute URL though.

Comment: I had a typo first and corrected it... maybe try again ? it works for me

Comment: 1st I would agree with people suggesting the CSS solution. 2nd I would heavily discourage the use of frames. But if you really want to use an <input>, then make sure that your 'rightframe' is created in HTML, make sure it has the name 'rightframe'. If it is just an iframe, my code will work. If it is a regular frame (ugly) then use top. instead of self.

Comment: well im working on a huge project. they have been developing it for 4 yrs.. i don't know much about it. there is already a link there. my boss wants it to be changed to a button. but it should open in the right frame.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to just use CSS, but if you're really stuck on using a physical button, you can create a dummy form with no data:

```
<form action="href"><input type="submit" value="Click Here" /></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours is working but this is better,

```
<input type="button" value="New booking" onClick="top.frames['rightframe'].src='add-lead-new.php'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
<a><?php echo( "<button onclick= \"location.href='inc/name_of_php_file.php'\">your buttons name goes here</button>");?></a>
```

In other words nest your desired php code block inside an anchor element to 'link' it. Then add the php code block and inside that code block you'll want to add an echo(). Inside that echo you want to add your HTML code like normal. As if you weren't even writing in PHP.

Edit the folder name and file to your desired location. And then finally edit what text you want your button to show your viewers.

onclick= \"location.href=**'folder_name_goes_here/name_of_php_file_goes_here.php**'\">**your buttons name goes here**

This should link to your page with your desired caption.

Please keep in mind the ***\"*** as this is utterly important. Without \ in front of the " your code wont read correctly due to the many "s found nested inside each other. \ allows HTML to ignore the first " as an end to the echo Sting.